# Service Worker: Cache HTML?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I'm writing a bible webpage, and I want to use a service worker.

I've got the following code in my service-worker.js:

```
var CACHE_NAME = 'my-site-cache-v1';
var urlsToCache = [
  '/',
  '/verse/_verse.js',
  '/verse/_verse.css',
  '/home/_home.js',
  '/home/_home.css',
  '/bookmarks/_bookmarks.js',
  '/bookmarks/_bookmarks.css',
  '/search/_search.js',
  '/search/_search.css'
];

self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  // Perform install steps
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
      .then(function(cache) {
        console.log('Opened cache');
        return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
      })
  );
});


self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request)
    .then(function(response) {
        // Cache hit - return response
        if (response) {
            console.log("found response")
            console.log(event.request.url)
            return response;
        }
        return fetch(event.request).then(
            function(response) {
                // Check if we received a valid response
                if(!response || response.status !== 200 || response.type !== 'basic') {
                    return response;
                }

                // IMPORTANT: Clone the response. A response is a stream
                // and because we want the browser to consume the response
                // as well as the cache consuming the response, we need
                // to clone it so we have two streams.
                var responseToCache = response.clone();

                caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
                    .then(function(cache) {
                    cache.put(event.request, responseToCache);
                });

                return response;
            }
        );
    })
);
});
```

Which is mostly code just taken from the [google service worker introduction.](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers)  However It seems to be only caching the images, css, js and font files - but I'd like it to cache the HTML of a page as well, to make it truly available offline.

All my content on my site is routed through to `index.php` and served from there, based off the REQUEST_URI.  How can I modify the service worker code to save the HTML of a URI request and serve it back in case its offline?

Comment: When you use `/` inside urlsToCache your root url which HTML of a URI request is already cached. if you want to target html content inside another folder like "home", etc. you can also use `/home/` inside urlsToCache.

Comment: If you’re using something like WordPress or Laravel (or, maybe, both) as I guess because of `index.php`, then you need to go further: dynamic PHP webpages should be served as static HTML files with a pre-render. Same for JavaScript routes with Vue.js, Angular, React, etc. on Node.js; that’s why you don’t see them cached IMHO.

Comment: @palaѕн are you saying they are already cached? is there a way to test it out?